# How to create 2D string vector and insert Data in it?

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

I have few strings with numbers at the end:
Say: **abc_0_0** **xyz_1_0** **dfg_0_1** **asd_2_0** **ghj_0_2** **iop_2_1** **hkk_1_1** **asv_2_2**
I can read them once at a time, Based on the numbers at the end, I need to create a 2D vector and insert the string element at the index given by the numbers.

So, for the given strings: index [0][0] should have **abc**, index [1][0] should have **xyz**, index [0][1] should have **dfg**, index [2][0] should have **asd**, index [0][2] should have **ghj**, index [2][1] should have **iop**, index [1][1] should have **hkk**, index [2][2] should have **asv**.

How can it be implemented? I don't know about the implementation of vector

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int maxentry;
    vector <vector <string>> Data;
    string s;
    char a;
    int c,d;
    cin >> maxentry;
    for(int j=0; j<maxentry; j++)
    {
        cin >> s;
        a=s[4];
        cout << s[4] << endl;
        cout << a <<endl;
        c = int (s[4])-int ('0');
        d = int (s[6])-int ('0');
        cout<< "Value: " <<c << " " << d << endl;
        Data[c][d]=s;  //Doesn't work here
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what have you implemented so far?

Comment: how can it be implemented? You create a 2d string vector and insert data into it.... the question is rather unclear. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @MarekChocholáček Hope this helps in understanding the question better!

Comment: @user463035818 I don't have idea about implementation of vectors. I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that std::vector is dynamic structure, which means it changes size. After default constructor of vector is called its size is 0. That means your 2D array is empty. One possible implementation is that you [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) it whenever you don't have enough space for corresponding indices:

```
for(int j=0; j<maxentry; j++)
{
    // ...
    c = int (s[4])-int ('0');
    d = int (s[6])-int ('0');
    if (Data.size() <= c)
        Data.resize(c + 1); // not enough space -> resize needed
    if (Data[c].size() <= d )
        Data[c].resize(d + 1); // not enough space -> resize needed
    // ...
}
```

If you don't want to resize and you know you will not need bigger 2D array than let's say 10x10 you can use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```
array< array< string, 10 >, 10 > Data;
```